# LSB warnings in systemd 15.10

Tags: runlevel

a get warnings by using a disable/enable systemd commands:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable mongodb.service 

Synchronizing state of mongodb.service with SysV init with    /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mongodb
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `mongodb' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `mongodb' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

how to fix that?
thx!